# How can I tell if my friend is broadcasting their location from an iPad vers an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, find-my-iphone, geolocation

I wondered if there was a way to tell the device being used to broadcast a location in Find My Friends. As in, if someone switched over their location from iPhone to iPad to show that they were at one place and left their iPad there to broadcast the location but weren't actually there?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to tell without physical access to one of the devices to look in the settings.

Comment: What about how the orange circle shows the location? The person is on the road verse being in the house?

Comment: @xxezwki The circle simply shows the location that is being broadcast for that particular Apple ID. The device which is broadcasting its location can be chosen in settings on one of the devices. It is not possible for someone else to find out which device this is without looking in settings on one of the devices which could be broadcasting the location (i.e. is logged in with the Apple ID).

Comment: Well that sucks. I guess if you don't trust someone you probably shouldn't be friends with them.